# Copy Constructor Static Analysis Tool?

Tags: c#

Is there any tooling out there that will let me tag a C# method / constructor as a copy-constructor and have it check that code for the obvious mistakes which can occur in a copy-constructor scneario?

Some obvious mistakes to check for:

- If it's supposed to be a deep copy but a shallow copy is obviously happening
- If it's supposed to be a shallow copy but a deep copy is happening
- Fields on the source which are not being copied
- Field on the target which are not being copied

There are probably other clever checks i haven't thought of.

I haven't found any tooling that has anything supporting this. Code Contracts seems like an obvious tool to have this, but i haven't found it if it does exist.

Outside of a static analysis tool, are there any other tricks to make sure copy-constructors stay up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is probably your best tool here.

C# doesn't create copy constructors automatically, like C++ and some other languages.  As such, this isn't typically the problem that it tends to be in C++.

In general, they tend to be far more rare in general in C# code than in many other languages.  As such, I suspect that you'd be better off including this check in your unit testing of those types, as needed, since they'll only be in a few specific types.

Comment: I agree. You're more likely to see an implementation of ICloneable, whose Clone() method is intended to create a deep copy of the object that implements the interface.

Comment: @KeithS Yes, this typically is handled another way in C#, either an explicit constructor (which may do anything), `ICloneable`, or a factory method to create the new instance, etc.  Since there are no automatic copy constructors, this is less of a problem in .NET.

Comment: Please don't use `ICloneable`. The documentation does not say that it requires deep copying nor does the interface have any way of enforcing such mechanics. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx